# Как оптимизировать код XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Утро доброе. Возникли трудности со стилями. Не могу сделать так чтобы один стиль применялся для всех тегов DataGridTextColumn, а именно Wrap и можно ли вообще сделать так чтобы параметр Wrap в одном стиле применялся для заголовок в столбцах и для элементов. Элементы загружаются после загрузки формы. Сейчас получилось сделать только так:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="WrappedRowStyle" >
       <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="WrappedColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
  </Style>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="1" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappedRowStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Элементы разных типов, поэтому один и тот же стиль можно применить только явно указав его ключ из ресурсов.

Comment: @АндрейNOP То есть как я понял стиль применить по тегу невозможно, только по ключу? Так же выше 2 стиля не объединить как понял не получится из-за того, что используются 2 разных параметра для элемента?

Comment: Ну у вас контролы разного типа TextBlock и DataGridColumnHeader, к ним можно применять один и тот же стиль, только если явно его указать

Comment: Можно убрать x:Key="WrappedRowStyle", тогда стиль применится ко всем TextBlock, расположенным в данном контейнере

Comment: @АндрейNOP В этом то и проблема, что убрав ключ x:Key="WrappedRowStyle", то стиль для DataGridTextColumn уже не действует. Кстати сам стиль находится в  DataGrid.Resources

Comment: Я вам про это и говорю. Поэтому только задавать ключ и только явно указывать стиль...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Понятно, спасибо за помощь